# How do I make decimal.TryParse keep the trailing zeros?

Tags: c#, .net, math

Currently if I do this

```
decimal d;
temp = "22.00";
decimal.TryParse(temp, NumberStyles.Any,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
```

Then 'd' turns out as 22. Is there any way I can ensure that trailing zeros don't get wiped out ?

FYI I am using .net 4.0

Comment: Why do you wish to do that. You can display trailing zeros when you use ToString for the UI...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same code works for me (displaying 22.00, and 22.000 if I change the input string to "22.000"), and as you've specified the invariant culture it shouldn't depend on *our* respective cultures.

How are you examining the value afterwards? If it's in the debugger, I wouldn't be surprised if that were to blame... if you print out `d.ToString()` what does that show?

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal d;
        decimal.TryParse("22.00", NumberStyles.Any,
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);

        // This prints out 22.00
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the issue, that i was seeing in the debugger :( Thanks. ToString() works fine and shows the trailing zeros

Comment: While this tells you what to do, it doesn't give the "why". Any number has infinate leading and trailing zeros. How do you imagine that a finite machine like a computer can store infinite values? It can't. So why would it arbitrarily store two of infinity? Since there are none stored, one can logically assume that displaying them is a matter for string conversion. See Decimal.ToString(string) in the docs for more information.

Comment: @Tergiver: `System.Decimal` maintains a precision, unlike (say) float and double which are normalized. In other words, 22, 22.0 and 22.00 are represented differently internally. So the number of trailing zeroes *is* stored, and at that point, your conclusion is invalid.

Comment: @Jon: That doesn't even make sense. Yes, Decimal stores numbers differently (low, mid, high, and flags). But to say that it stores trailing zeros seems irrational to me. I need more than just your word for that one.

Comment: @Tergiver: Try `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 22m, 22.0m, 22.00m);` and you'll see proof. And use Decimal.GetBits to find the underlying bits for each of those values - you'll see they differ. Will look for documentation to back it up too.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't hard to find. From the docs for System.Decimal: "The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeroes in a Decimal number. Trailing zeroes do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeroes can be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx

Comment: (The trailing zeroes are *implicit* in the scaling factor, effectively. So 2200 with a scaling factor of 2 is *equal* to 22 with a scaling factor of 0, but has two trailing zeroes.)

Comment: Thanks @Jon. The last comment clinched it for me. I had forgotten that decimal uses scaling for precision. I'm ok with being wrong. Hopefully I'm not the only one who learned something =)

Comment: I see questions over and over again where people demonstrate that they don't understand the distinction between how numeric values are stored and how they are displayed (especially true for DateTime). In the case of Decimal, there is *some* need to understand storage (scaling factor), but for most numeric types it's not relevant. What's important is that all numbers must be converted to strings in order to be displayed. That's true for a debugger just as it's true for your application. When converting to string representation there are formatting specifiers available.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no and to just format the decimal with trailing zeros on display as 22 is still 22.00.

Comment: No, 22 isn't 22.00 in terms of the representation inside `System.Decimal`. It's not a normalized floating point type.

Comment: I ment there is no difference in value between 22 and 22.00 but intresting :)

Comment: There's no difference in magnitude, but certain systems do want to maintain the number of significant digits - e.g. it could affect how rounding is performed later on.

Answer (score 0):

> Then 'd' turns out as 22

And you expect to turn into what? The zeros are still there:

```
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was seeing in debugger so i was not seeing  the trailing zeros