# Decimal.Parse removes trailing zero

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to cast a string value as a Decimal for an ObjectParameter and the decimal must be to two places in precision for the Stored procedure.

It basically looks like this:

```
string scScore = "1.50";

decimal scScore2 = Decimal.Parse(scScore);
```

I expect scScore2 to equal 1.50 but it always ends up as 1.5 no matter how I try to cast it.

This code does exactly what I want when I run it in C# fiddle or in VS in a new console application. I have tried just about every method I have found on this site and others to maintain my trailing zero, but it always seems to get lost.

I have also tried to add a trailing zero after the parse, but this never works either.

What else could be causing this?

EDIT:

I was misled by looking at values in debugger.

Output was indeed as one would expect.

Comment: @David it's a little known fact, but decimals have a precision too. See [this example](http://ideone.com/2KYNqo).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Interesting.  Good to know.  (Seems useful for scientific calculations where precision matters, regardless of the value.)  A little Googling after learning that led me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324988/how-do-i-make-decimal-tryparse-keep-the-trailing-zeros  Not only does that make this a duplicate question, but the answer seems simple enough.  The OP is probably looking at the value in the debugger, not in actual output.  Tests confirm that `.ToString()` on the resulting value *does* output `"1.50"`.

Comment: @David Yes, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8705861/3764814) when looking for a dupe, but yours fits better with this question.

Comment: @David Confirmed by output System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(scScore2) I was misled. Anything I can read about why this is the case and not be misled in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Decimals don't have trailing zeroes.

If you need that, it is for display only. Apply a format for a string, like "0.00".

Comment: You're wrong. [They do](http://ideone.com/2KYNqo) :)

Comment: Well, that's for fun only. Try `22m.Equals(22.00m)`.

Comment: I didn't say the values weren't equal ;-)